# How to understand this code line?

Tags: scala, scala.js, scalajs-react

What is this [code line](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/gh-pages/src/main/scala/ghpages/examples/TodoExample.scala#L71) doing? Is this syntactic sugar for another notation?

```
def createItem(itemText: String) = <.li(itemText)
<.ul(props map createItem: _*)                       <-- this one
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you find the line too strange from a purely syntactical point of view.

The `<` is a member of another strangely named entity [`html_<^`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react/core_sjs0.6_2.11/1.2.0/index.html#japgolly.scalajs.react.vdom.html_$less$up$).

The `<` gizmo is of type [HtmlTags](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react/core_sjs0.6_2.11/1.2.0/index.html#japgolly.scalajs.react.vdom.HtmlTags$), and in particular it has methods `li` and `ul`, that correspond to tags `<li>` and `<ul>`.

Therefore `<.ul(foobar)` is a method call on `<` of the method `ul` with arguments `foobar`.

The `foo: _*` syntax is for passing collections to vararg methods.

To summarize:

- `props` is some collection that is
- mapped using a function `createItem` and the result is then
- passed as vararg to method `ul` of
- the `HtmlType`-typed member `<` of
- the object / package `html_<^`

So, essentially, it just constructs an unordered list of some sort.

Here is a brief explanation from the [project github page](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/VDOM.md#basics) about the naming of these methods:

> Tags and tag attributes are namespaced; tags under < (because <.div looks similar to ), and attributes under ^ (because something concise was needed and you usually have many attributes which written on new lines all looks to point up back to the target tag).

Comment: Thanks. Because of you, I found the correct places for the parenthesis. `<.ul(props.map(createItem): _*)` Now it is easier for me to understand it :)

Comment: @user1091344 Ah, that's another kind of syntactic sugar. You can usually write `foo.bar(baz)` in infix notation `foo bar baz`.